# X-Axis as zero line in MPChart Line Chart

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart library to show positive and negative values in Line Chart graph. I have enabled zero line using `leftAxis.setDrawZeroLine(true)`. My question is can I show X-Axis in place of zero line? As in below example screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try `chart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(yourLabelCount, true);` ?

Comment: That method is to force label count, right. I already have that in my code. It doesn't work.